# Difference between bundle.js, 0.chunk.js, main.chunk.js

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, code-splitting, dynamic-import

After my **React** app loaded in the network tab of dev tools I have filtered the .js extension there I can see **bundle.js, 0.chunk.js, main.chunk.js, Landingpage.chunk.js**, etc files.

I can understand that Landingpage.chunk.js is the chunk that is related to the currently loaded page from the react-router, as I have added dynamic import syntax for code splitting for the Landing page component at the route level.

But I want to know what is the behavior of these files **bundle.js, 0.chunk.js, main.chunk.js**

can anyone explain, please?